# How to solve an internal function naming clashing?

Tags: matlab

I have been searching online for the answer of this question(including this site of course where I couldn't really find a satisfactory solution). My problem is the `AddParameter` function in class `inputParser` is conflicting with the function `AddParameter` in a Matlab toolbox function `cgoptimoptions` under package mbc:

which addParameter
E:\study\compilers\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\mbc\mbcdata\@cgoptimoptions\addParameter.m  % cgoptimoptions method

You see. I have been careful with the naming strategy of my own code. But this time it seems that it is the naming clashing between two internal functions (I call them internal functions because I assume that the AddParameter for inputParser is a built-in, and the one in the toolbox is also released by Mathworks as part of the IDE toolkits, so kinda also "official").

By looking into the function precedence and posts by others, I am aware that there are two things I can do to fix it: either change the names or manipulate the paths. Well, I don't like either of them because the first one will mess up the whole naming strategy clearly preferred by MathWorks and the second one does not really solve the problem if at some point I do need to use both of them.

So could you please give me some tips on how to systematically avoid this kind issues? It's been very frustrating for me.

Comment: They are methods, not functions, right? If so, how can they conflict? Can you post some code example where you call one and it turns out to call the other?

Comment: OK, so you are calling AddParameter from inputParser. Are you saying the call is made to the toolbox @cgoptimoptions\addParameter.m ?

Comment: thanks, seb. I believe they are functions. Sorry for not being clear before. A simple AddParameter call in my method will give "Undefined function 'addParameter' for input arguments of type 'inputParser'". For example function TR = render(varargin){ p = inputParser; AddParameter(p, 'normalize', range); ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
addParameter(p, 'normalize', normalize);
```

Use:

```
p.addParameter('normalize', normalize);
```

But it looks like `addParameter` is not part of the class `inputParser`. Use this to find the method to use:

```
methods(p)
```

It seems the class `inputParser` includes a method `addParamValue` but not `addParameter`.

Comment: thanks. I think addParamValue might work too. But I checked it before and somehow it was labelled as "not recommended" in the docs from MathWorks. It was why I used addParameter instead of addParamValue. You are right that inputParser doesn't include addParameter. So it must be a function I guess.

Comment: If p.<method>() does not work, then don't try to use <method>(p) instead, because if it works, it's probably not gonna do what you want anyway.

Comment: I agree. So that's why I think this is two functions clashing. Any other suggestions on the original question?

Comment: As suggested, if you use `p.<method>` you will solve the name clash problem. If there is an error, it's not a problem of name clash, it's just that the method does not exist (in the current version) and you can verify this using `methods(inputParser)`.

Comment: I see where the problem is. Because I ran it on a different machine it worked well, so I naturally assumed it should work on the current machine. I forgot to check the version of the matlab. You are right, this might not be a problem of naming clashing. So there is no addParameter function in Matlab 2012a. Thanks for the help seb.